# Datables con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

Hola estoy usando Datables, la tabla la lleno atreves de una petición de ajax con jquery de esta manera:

```
         $('.tabla_productos').append("<tr><td>" + datos[a]['nombre'] + "</td><td>" + datos[a]['codigo'] +
            "</td><td><span class='badge bg-warning'>"+  datos[a]['stock'] +"</span></td></tr>");
```

De esa manera lleno la tabla obviamente con un bucle for y luego llamo a el método :

```
$('#tabla_productos').DataTable();
```

Esta es mi pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando uso el input search de datables me salen los datos de la consulta anterior, osea no refresca la tabla al llenar con ajax  con los nuevos datos.

Comment: ¿Esto lo has probado?  `$('#tabla_productos').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

Si es un llenado en la primera carga y no un llenado dinámico cuando ya existe la tabla, la forma correcta de llenar la tabla es con un array, uqe se pasa al atributo data, del llamado en ajax y el plugín sólo construirá cada fila nueva, debe haber una coherencia entre el nombre de las columnas que llegan en el ajax y el nombre de las columnas del javascript para que arrastre los datos correctamente. Aquí s emuestra varias alternativas de hacerlo, https://datatables.net/manual/ajax